how to enable Gmail API (machine-2-machine comms) via GCP
these are the current instructions I see:
Step 1: Enable Domain-Wide Delegation in Google Admin Console
Go to Admin Console.
Navigate to:

Security > API Controls > Domain-Wide Delegation.

Click Add New to create a new delegation.
Add the Client ID from your Service Account JSON file (the client_id field).
Add the required OAuth scopes as a comma-separated list:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

the problem is that the 2nd and 3rd item don't exist

Security > API Controls > Domain-Wide Delegation

I cannot find API Controls or Domain-Wide Delegation
anyone know what to look for?

note the current documentations seems like bs - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority
